# Flash AS3 Error: 1013: The private attribute may be used only on class property definitions

Tags: actionscript-3, class, actionscript

> C:\Users\Lab3project\MainDocument.as, Line 103, Column 7  1013: The
>   private attribute may be used only on class property definitions.

The lines of code concerned:

```
 package  {
    //these are flash built-in classes
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.Event;
    //Our own custom class
     import MainTimer;  

    public class MainDocument extends MovieClip{

        private var gameTimer:MainTimer;
        private var thePlayer:Player;
        private var theEnemy:Enemy;
        private var maxEnemies: int = 3;
        private var e:int = 0;
        private var childrenOnStage:int;

        public function MainDocument() {
            // constructor code
            trace("the main document is alive");

            // new instance MainTimer class
            gameTimer = new MainTimer();

            // must add it to the stage
            addChild(gameTimer);
            //adjust its postion on stage
            gameTimer.x = 20;
            gameTimer.y = 20;

            //add the player
             thePlayer = new Player();
            addChild(thePlayer);
            // adjust its postion on the stage
            thePlayer.x = stage.stageWidth * 0.5;
            //assign the name property
              thePlayer.name = "player";

              while(e < maxEnemies){
                  createEnemy();
                  e++;
              } //end while

                //Update this variable every time a child is added to the stage
                  childrenOnStage = this.numChildren

               // Add event listener to control timing of main game loop
                  addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,mainGameLoop);

          }//end function MainDocument

            private function createEnemy():void{
                trace("create enemy");
                theEnemy = new Enemy();
                addChild(theEnemy);
                //Place in a random spot on stage
                theEnemy.x = (Match.random() * stage.stageWidth);
                theEnemy.y = 0;

                //assign the name property
                  theEnemy.name = "enemy";

                //Update this variable every time a child is added to the stage
                  childrenOnStage = this.numChildren
                } //end function    createEnemy

            //the main loop for the game
             private function mainGameLoop(event:Event): void{

                checkForGameReset();

                processCollisions();

                scrollStage();

            } // end functiom mainGameLoop
              private function checkForGameReset():void{
                  //define conditions
              } //end function checkForGameReset

              private function processCollisions():void{
                  //set up the main loop to look through all collidale objects on stage
                  for(var c:int;c < childOnStage;c++){
                      //trace ("Child on stage c= " + c +
                      //test for a player of enemy child on stage
            if (getChildAt(c).name == "player" || getChildAt(c).name == "enemy"){ 
                //see if object is touching the game stage
                if( theGameStage.hitTestPoint(getChildAt(c).x, getChildAt(c).y,true)){
                    //while it is still touching the game stage
                    while( theGameStage.hitTestPoint(getChildAt(c).x, getChildAt(c).y,true)==true){
                        //called from CollisionObject class,so force the connection
                        CollisionObject(getChildAt(c)).incrementUpward();
                    if( theGameStage.hitTestPoint(getChildAt(c).x, getChildAt(c).y,true)==false){
                    }CollisionObject(getChildAt(c)).keepOnBoundary(); //make it stick
                   } // end if
                  } // end while
                 } //end if touching
                } //end if player or enemy
              } //end for loop
            } //end function processCollisions

The lines of code concerned: is here where im getting the error 
   private function scrollStage(): void
    {
        // figure out logic
    }
    //  end function scrollStage


            //add the enemy for testing
             theEnemy = new Enemy();
            addChild(theEnemy);
            // adjust its postion on the stage
            theEnemy.x = stage.stageWidth * 0.5;
            theEnemy.y = 200;



        }  // end public function MainDocument

    } // end public class


} // end package
```

After I have change that code ,it then says I have a extra character at the end but the characters I have to have at the end.

Comment: Post your entire MainDocument.as if you can. Most likely you've either not put the method shown within the class declaration (or have nested it improperly some other way).

Answer (score 3):

Problems like this often occur because of a slight typo in syntax. Perhaps you have accidentally declared your private function within another function?

```
public function doSomething() {
    //a whole bunch of stuff
//then we forget to close the function with a brace "}"

private function scrollStage() {
    //but we're still defining doSomething! Throw error!
}
```

Go and look for errors like this, and hopefully you can find the problem.